# pi over prime number radians

Tags: geometry, prime-numbers

Is $\pi/p$ is where $p$ is odd prime number is the angle found in the vertex of the regular polygon star with Schläfli symbol $\{p/\Big(\frac{p-1}{2}\Big)\}$

I tried several number when $p=3$ the shape is triangle

When $p=5$ it's a pentagram whose vertex have angle of $\pi/5$